# Apache Virtual Hosts direct IP Access

Tags: apache, hosts

I have various virtual hosts running. I know that people could access these by adding an entry to their hosts file, but is it possible to access to one specific virtual using the IP + something else?

e.g. http://`<server_ip>`/`<host>`/

Comment: Please post an example of your `VirtualHost`

Comment: http://codeshare.io/Y3oJx

Comment: I know using user directorys one could access with
http://<server_ip>/~username

but I'm asking for virtual hosts instead

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the line of:

```
    <Location />
       <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
           RewriteEngine on
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -s [OR]
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -l [OR]
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d

           RewriteRule ^([^/)+(.*)$ /srv/http/$1/public/$2 [NC,L]
       </IfModule>
    </Location>
```

This would be placed in your default `VirtualHost`